# How does one iterate through an array to make different urls?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a little array and create urls out of the information contained therein.

Here's a dummy setup of what I'm trying to do:

```py
import urllib.parse
DEEP_CAT_URL = 'https://google.com/search?q=%s'

def GetCatLink(cats=()):
  for cat in cats:
    cat_id = cat['name']
    color = cat.get('color')
    if color:
      deep_cat_url = DEEP_CAT_URL % urllib.parse.quote(color+'+cat',safe='+')
      return (deep_cat_url)


CATS = [
    {
        'color': 'red',
        'name': 'Redd Foxx',
    },
    {
        'color': 'black',
        'name': 'Donnie Darko',
    },
]

print("There are "+str(len(CATS))+" cats to consider")

for h in range(len(CATS)):
  cnum=str(h+1)
  print("Cat #"+cnum+":")
  if CATS[h]["color"] != '':
    print("The name of Cat #{} is {}. The color of {} is {}.".format(cnum,CATS[h]["name"],CATS[h]["name"], CATS[h]["color"]))
    x=CATS[h]
    print(x)
    print(GetCatLink(CATS))
```

It kind of works, but outputs:

```
There are 2 cats to consider
Cat #1:
The name of Cat #1 is Redd Foxx. The color of Redd Foxx is red.
{'color': 'red', 'name': 'Redd Foxx'}
https://google.com/search?q=red+cat
Cat #2:
The name of Cat #2 is Donnie Darko. The color of Donnie Darko is black.
{'color': 'black', 'name': 'Donnie Darko'}
https://google.com/search?q=red+cat
```

The goal here is to have two urls:

Cat#1 `https://google.com/search?q=red+cat`

Cat#2 `https://google.com/search?q=black+cat`

Comment: You're looping over all cats in `GetCatLink` and on the first iteration, you return a URL - so you always get the URL for the first cat in `CATS`. There's no reason to do any looping over there, why not pass the cat you want a URL for to the function and just process that one?

Comment: Also should mention that unless you're doing something really "tricksy" - Google isn't going to honour URLs if you make them as a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `GetCatLink` and its invocation needs to be modified. Then everything works well.

```py
def GetCatLink(cat):
    color = cat.get('color')
    if color:
        return DEEP_CAT_URL % urllib.parse.quote(color + '+cat', safe='+')

for h in range(len(CATS)):
    cnum = str(h + 1)
    print("Cat #" + cnum + ":")
    if CATS[h]["color"] != '':
        print("The name of Cat #{} is {}. The color of {} is {}.".format(cnum, CATS[h]["name"], CATS[h]["name"],
                                                                         CATS[h]["color"]))
        x = CATS[h]
        print(x)
        print(GetCatLink(CATS[h]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looping over all cats in GetCatLink and on the first iteration, you return a URL - so you always get the URL for the first cat in CATS. There's no reason to do any looping over there, why not pass the cat you want a URL for to the function and just process that one?

Instead of:

```
def GetCatLink(cats=()):
  for cat in cats:
    cat_id = cat['name']
    color = cat.get('color')
    if color:
      deep_cat_url = DEEP_CAT_URL % urllib.parse.quote(color+'+cat',safe='+')
      return (deep_cat_url)
```

Use:

```
def get_cat_link(cat):
    cat_id = cat['name']
    color = cat.get('color')
    return DEEP_CAT_URL % urllib.parse.quote(color + '+cat', safe='+')
```

And instead of this:

```
print(GetCatLink(CATS))
```

This:

```
print(get_cat_link(x))
```

There's more to be said about your code - there's some surplus stuff in there, but this addresses your main issue.

(As @JonClements correctly comments: you will run into trouble if you try make requests with the URLs you're creating, unless you use them in a normal browser. Google won't give you the result you expect if you just use `urllib` or `requests` without getting "tricksy".)

Comment: Might also want to look at `urllib.parse.urlencode`...